# Removing 3-letter abbreviations in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column full of journal article titles in excel, and I need to extract cognitive concepts or technical terms from them. One of the preprocessing parts includes removing abbreviations that are commonly used but do not represent a concept, like NGC for New General Catalogue or VLA for Very Large Array in Astronomy. Almost all of these abbreviations are 3-letter words, all capitalized. Is there a way to remove these words? I have Kutools installed in excel, if that matters.

**EDIT:** I've attached an image of some of the titles. All the titles are in a single column, with each title in one cell. In the attached picture, I'd like to remove AWM, ESO, SFI, NGC. There is no distinction as such to be made here between commonly used abbreviations and technical terms, other than the fact that in my case, technical terms need to be words or phrases. Even if these abbreviations mean something, they do not represent a concept in my data and thus need to be removed in order to not skew the data analysis due to their frequency.

[image]

Comment: You should edit your post and add a sample data or image to show how the cells with these abbreviations are structured. Also, how do you differentiate between "commonly used" abbreviations and those that are not?

Comment: A quick and dirty way could be to do a find and replace all ctrl + h, but that would only work if you know all possible abbreviations. You can also use the match case to make sure you're only getting the capitalized ones.

Answer (score 2):

TBH the VBA approach might be simpler, but I like to learn if things are possible in PowerQuery regardless!

The answer is yes! I copied your text into a table and made the column header "data".

This query then removes the TLAs from the text:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed type from mixed to text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"data", type text}}),
    #"Added Index to enable split/apply/combine" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed type from mixed to text", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Split each sentence by space onto new rows" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index to enable split/apply/combine", {{"data", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "data"),
    #"Add a column to identify Three-Letter-Acronyms (TLA)" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split each sentence by space onto new rows", "TLA", each Text.Length([data])=3 
and Text.Upper([data]) = [data] 
and Value.Is(Value.FromText([data]), type text)),
    #"Filter the rows so that TLAs are hidden" = Table.SelectRows(#"Add a column to identify Three-Letter-Acronyms (TLA)", each ([TLA] = false)),
    #"Hide the TLA column (it's no longer needed)" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filter the rows so that TLAs are hidden",{"TLA"}),
    #"Group by index, concat. text using space delimiter" = Table.Group(#"Hide the TLA column (it's no longer needed)", {"Index"}, {{"data", each Text.Combine([data]," "), type text}}),
    #"Remove the index" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Group by index, concat. text using space delimiter",{"Index"})
in
    #"Remove the index"
```

When it's finished, it looks like this:

[image]

Nearly all of this can be done with the UI, with the exception of the Group By step, where you need to first Group By Index and Sum the data, which of course produces an  error, then edit the query in the Advanced Editor to change the Sum operation to `Text.Combine` with a space as the delimiter.

Comment: +1 Great thinking

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub KleanUp()
    arr = Array("AWM", "ESO", "SFI", "NGC")
    For Each a In arr
        Cells.Replace what:=a, replacement:=""
    Next a
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

**NOTES:**

1. You can expand the `Array()` statement to include any other sub-strings you need to remove.
2. The sub-strings can appear anywhere in the string.
3. A single cell can contain more than one sub-string.
4. Using `Range.Replace` avoids the need to loop over each cell in the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VBA code for this:

```
Sub Calc()
  Dim intC As Integer
  Dim objR As Object
  Set objR = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")
  With objR 
    .Pattern = ".*[A-Z]{3}.*" 
    .IgnoreCase = False
  End With
  intC = 10 ' MAKE SURE TO REPLACE 10 WITH THE LAST CELL NUMBER OF YOUR COLUMN
  For i = 1 To intC 
    If objR.Test(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
      Range("A" & 1).Value = ""
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You code as it currently is removes the remove the content of cell A1. Remember, the OP wants to remove only abbreviations, not the whole content of a cell.

Comment: Ok @ReddyLutonadio I will do this soon.. Just need to get the matches and do replace